# How to save int data from TextFormField in Flutter

Tags: flutter

I made some `TextFormField`, and I want to save the data in `int` when I press the `FlatButton`. When I press `FlatButton`, I want him to check whether the sum of `TextFormField` expenses and savings is not greater than `TextFormField` income. if the sum of the `TextTormField` expenses and savings is greater, I want to display `errortext` under the textformfield savings "your expenses and savings are greater than your income"

```
class BigNotePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _BigNotePageState createState() => _BigNotePageState();
}

class _BigNotePageState extends State<BigNotePage> {
  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  String _income;
  String _expenses;
  String _savings;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      padding: kPading,
      child: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: [
          TitlePage('Big Note'),
          Expanded(
            child: Form(
              key: _formKey,
              child: Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: [
                  TxtField(
                    label: 'Income',
                    function: (value) => _income = value,
                  ),
                  TxtField(
                    label: 'Expenses',
                    function: (value) => _expenses = value,
                  ),
                  TxtField(
                    label: 'Savings',
                    function: (value) => _savings = value,
                  ),
                  FlatButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      int.parse(_income) >=
                              int.parse(_expenses) + int.parse(_savings)
                          ? _formKey.currentState.save()
                          : print('null');
                    },
                    child: Text(
                      'WRITE THAT',
                      style: TextStyle(letterSpacing: 1.25),
                    ),
                    color: Colors.yellow,
                    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30.0),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Container(
            width: 250.0,
            child: Text(
              '*if you get another income for this mounth, input the income again.',
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12.0),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class TxtField extends StatelessWidget {
  TxtField({this.label, this.function});

  final String label;
  final Function function;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 8.0),
      child: TextFormField(
        onSaved: function,
        keyboardType: TextInputType.numberWithOptions(decimal: true),
        decoration: InputDecoration(
          labelText: label,
          prefix: Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            child: Text(
              'IDR',
              style:
                  TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image: My App Look like this]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace String values to the controller values

```
final _incomeController = TextEditingController();
final _expenseController = TextEditingController();
final _savingController = TextEditingController();
```

Also, add

bool _validate = false;

Convert String value to int of your TextField:

```
        TextField(
                controller: _incomeController,
                label: 'Income',
                 decoration: InputDecoration(
                  errorText: _validate ? 'Your message' : null,
                 ),
              ),
              TextField( 
                controller: _expenseController ,
                label: 'Expenses',
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                  errorText: _validate ? 'Your message' : null,
                  ),
              ),
              TextField(
               controller: _savingController,
                label: 'Savings',
                 decoration: InputDecoration(
                  errorText: _validate ? 'Your message' : null,
                 ),
              ),
```

Now FlatButton Logic:

```
              onPressed: () {

                     String _income = _incomeController.text;
                     String _expenses = _expenseController.text;
                     String _savings = _savingController.text;
  
                      int.parse(_income) >=
                              int.parse(_expenses) + int.parse(_savings)
                          ? _formKey.currentState.save()
                          : print('null');
                    },
```

Rest apply your logic wherever you want.

Comment: i've try you recomendation, and then my flatbutton get error when i pressed 
"The method '+' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: +(null)"

Comment: @RanduPratama: Edited the answer, it should work for you now